# XCodeDeviceMonitor taking all system memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios-simulator

When debugger starts, in case of app crash or debug enabled, process XCodeDeviceMonitor starts using all system memory. Why? Anyone had this problem?

Comment: I am suffering from this as well.  Started in XCode 5 and goes well into 5.1

The only thing that stops it is restarting XCode.  If you don't restart it XCode will bring down the system and just freeze the entire OS X interface.