# My app frequently but randomly crashes the entire phone on application load

Tags: ios, debugging, crash, ios7

I recently started testing my iPhone app on my iPhone 5S device directly from XCode 5's debugger, and it seems to randomly crash the entire phone. I cannot pinpoint what the exact issue is. I'm not doing anything at all in my AppDelegate, so I don't believe it's related to something on load time. Sometimes performing a delete of the application, then a reset of the phone, and then a clearing of XCode's entire cache temporarily fixes the problem, but then it spontaneously comes back. It's very inconsistent. I'm at a complete loss at this point. The latest crash finally showed the following error message on the device itself:

> Incident Identifier: 4180F1E2-E932-417A-92BE-82F2C414FB82
>   CrashReporter Key:   e3cdd62843930ef2e7bcffbdb79479abc6141800 Hardware
>   Model:      iPhone6,1 Process:             XcodeDeviceMonitor [230]
>   Path:                /Developer/usr/bin/XcodeDeviceMonitor Identifier:
>   XcodeDeviceMonitor Version:             ??? Code Type:           ARM
>   (Native) Parent Process:      launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time:           2013-11-09 18:54:39.040 -0500 OS Version:
>   iOS 7.0.3 (11B511) Report Version:      104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000e7ffdefe Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Dyld Error Message:   Library not loaded: /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
>   Referenced from: /Developer/usr/bin/XcodeDeviceMonitor   Reason: image
>   not found   Dyld Version: 324
>
> Binary Images: 0x2befb000 - 0x2bf1efff dyld armv7s 
>    /usr/lib/dyld

Comment: As a registered developer, you get two support incidents per year. I'd suggest if no solution appears soon to use one of them on this. good luck

Comment: I may have to try that. I found that sometimes deleting the "DerivedData" folder helps. Sometimes. It's really interesting as it appears to sometimes happen when I close XCode and then reopen it up again. I'm surprised I'm having such a tough time finding someone with a similar issue.

Comment: In the interest of getting a bit more specific about when it occurs:
1) Does it ever happen when Xcode is not attached to the process? In other words, does it ever happen if you launch the app from the phone without the phone attached to the computer?
2) Does it happen in the simulator? Do you have other devices that the problem does not occur on?

Comment: 1) I have not been able to reproduce it when Xcode is not attached to the process. That being said, I have only recently started testing it on the device in general, so I haven't tested it enough outside of Xcode. 2) It 100% does not happen in the simulator. I have had issues with Xcode where it loses its connection to the simulator, but not crashes like this. Unfortunately this is the only device I have. I have even factory reset the device and it still comes back.

Comment: I don't know if this post is still relevant, but this problem could be related to memory issues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541240/xcodedevicemonitor-taking-all-system-memory

Answer (score 0):

Given the reference to a breakpoint in the crash log, I do have one idea. In the past, I have seen Xcode crash my apps on launch *if* breakpoints are enabled. Try **disabling breakpoints before launching the app**, then enabling them shortly after launch, if you are using any. Let me know if this seems to make any sort of consistent difference!

Comment: I just tried doing that, but didn't help. I have just recently gotten the device crashes again, and no matter what I do I can't get rid of them. I've reset my computer, closed xcode a billion times, cleared that DerivedData folder, performed a clean, reset the device. Etc. The first run of the application always works, but then the 2nd run crashes the entire phone. I did notice this error now, which I did not see before:

Comment: Nov  9 20:08:25 iPhone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[153] <Error>: error: In completion handler for send event, got error "The operation couldn’t be completed. (BKSSystemServiceDomain error 6.)"(6).
Nov  9 20:08:25 iPhone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[153] <Error>: error: unable to launch the application with CFBundleIdentifier 'com.bps.Gallery' bks_error = 6
Nov  9 20:08:25 iPhone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[153] <Warning>: 1 +0.000000 sec [0099/060b]: RNBRunLoopLaunchInferior DNBProcessLaunch() returned error: 'Busy'

Comment: Nov  9 20:08:25 iPhone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[153] <Warning>: error: failed to launch process /Developer/usr/bin/debugserver: Busy
Nov  9 20:08:25 iPhone com.apple.debugserver-300.2[153] <Warning>: 2 +0.001881 sec [0099/1207]: error: ::read ( -1, 0x1005aba38, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the latest version of Xcode (5.0.2) that was released this past week resolved my issue. At least I haven't seen it since I applied the patch. I noticed one of the major issues fixed was for the debugger crashing the phone on iOS 6, but I suspect whatever they did also fixed my similar issue for iOS 7. Anyway, it's acting much more consistent now. Thanks for everyone's help.